# MYSQL, Get only first rows with unique id from colum with multiple same value rows?

Tags: mysql, select, unique, unique-key

I have two tables `user_photos` and `user_annons`, I fetch from both using `join`.

In the `user_annons` each row is always with a unique id, the Id column is auto increment, and the randomkey colum is also unique.

But in the `user_photos` table there can be multiple rows with the same randomkey value, and the randomkey value is the same as in `user_annons`. `user_photos` table also have an id column that is auto increment.

My code looks like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT iname, title, pris 
                        FROM user_annons 
                        JOIN user_photos 
                        ON user_photos.randomkey = user_annons.randomkey 
                        AND user_annons.profile_id='".$profile_id."' 
                        AND user_photos.profile_id='".$profile_id."'");

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<a href=\"".$profile_id."/images/".$row2['iname']."\">
    <img src=\"".$profile_id."/images/".$row2['iname']."\"></a>";
    echo $row2['title'];
    echo $row2['pris'];
}
```

What I want is to fetch the only row with the unique randomkey value in the `user_annons` table, together with the first unique randomkey row in `user_photos` table.

Now the code displays a picture first and then the title and pris from u`ser_annons`, and then a different picture but the same title and pris from `user_annons`, because there is one row in `user_annons` but two rows in `user_photos` with the same randomkey value.

So is there anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use LIMIT 1

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT iname, title, pris 
                        FROM user_annons 
                        JOIN user_photos 
                        ON user_photos.randomkey = user_annons.randomkey 
                        AND user_annons.profile_id='".$profile_id."' 
                        AND user_photos.profile_id='".$profile_id."' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: I have tried this and it only returns 1 row. And i want all the first rows that have a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ua.iname, 
    ua.title, 
    ua.pris,
    up.profile_id
FROM user_annons as ua
JOIN (select min(id) as up_id , randomkey , profile_id from  user_photos) as up ON up.randomkey = ua.randomkey 
AND ua.profile_id='".$profile_id."' 
AND up.profile_id='".$profile_id."'
```

Using MIN() will fetch the first matching row and if you use MAX it will fetch the last one

Comment: It doesn't work. Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login_Script\view.php on line 39

Comment: it does not work because you havent modified it according to your requirements you should learn to use subqueries in joins

Comment: I did try to modify it to my requirements but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If i run a SQL query the problem is this: #1054 - Unknown column 'up.iname' in 'field list', I think it is the user_photos isn't getting the AS up alias?

Comment: its not up.iname according to the query it should ua.iname

Comment: But the colum iname is from user_photos table. So how to get iname from user_photos and title and pris from user_annons?

Comment: select columns according to your requirements not my requirements aslo select columns in left join they will work then